# Null reference exception in Microsoft.Rtc.Admin.AuthenticationHelper while trying to run powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the code which tries to get a lync session running powershell script form c#. When trying to run the script      **"$CSSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $cred\n"** I am getting null reference exception.

**Stack Trace:**

> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.   Source=System.Management.Automation
>   WasThrownFromThrowStatement=false   StackTrace:
>          at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
>          at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input,
>   Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements,
>   CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][]
>   commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)   InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
>          HResult=-2147467261
>          Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>          Source=Microsoft.Rtc.Admin.AuthenticationHelper
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Admin.Authentication.ManagedIdcrl..ctor(IDCRLMode mode)
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Admin.Authentication.ManagedIdcrl..ctor()
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.LyncOnlineConnector.GetWebTicketCmdlet.CreateAndInitializeManagedIdcrl()
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.LyncOnlineConnector.GetWebTicketCmdlet.get_ManagedIdcrl()
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.LyncOnlineConnector.GetWebTicketCmdlet.GetLiveIdToken(String
>   remoteFqdn, Int32 port, PSCredential creds)
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.LyncOnlineConnector.GetWebTicketCmdlet.ConnectToWebTicketService(String
>   fqdn, Int32 port, PSCredential creds)
>               at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.LyncOnlineConnector.GetWebTicketCmdlet.BeginProcessing()
>               at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()
>               at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
>          InnerException:

**Code is :**

```
    public static void GetLyncUsers(string userName, string plainPassword)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        using (Runspace myRs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config))
        {
            myRs.Open();

            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(myRs);
            scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

            using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShellInstance.Runspace = myRs;

                // Import module.
                powerShellInstance.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module")
                    .AddArgument(
                        @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Lync Server 2013\Modules\LyncOnlineConnector\LyncOnlineConnector.psd1");
                powerShellInstance.Invoke();
                powerShellInstance.Commands.Clear();


                // Set credentials
                SecureString password = new SecureString();
                foreach (var passChar in plainPassword)
                {
                    password.AppendChar(passChar);
                }

                PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, password);
                powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
                powerShellInstance.AddParameter("Name", "cred");
                powerShellInstance.AddParameter("Value", credential);
                powerShellInstance.Invoke();
                powerShellInstance.Commands.Clear();

                // Run the script 
                var script = string.Format(
                    "$CSSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $cred\n");
                powerShellInstance.AddScript(script);
                Collection<PSObject> psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke(); //Getting exception here.

                // check the other output streams (for example, the error stream)
                if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    // error records were written to the error stream.
                    // do something with the items found.
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told my MS support that invoking Lync Online PowerShell script from C# is currently not supported.